# How can I perform another action of another controller (rendering too) in Rails 2.3.5 without a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I know that it's totally against the MVC, but anyway it must be done that way. So I need something like that:

```
app/controllers/controller_a.rb
class ControllerA < ApplicationController
  def index
    some_code
  end
end

app/controllers/controller_b.rb
class ControllerB < ApplicationController
  def other_index
    @var = 'example'
  end
end

app/views/controller_b/other_index.html.erb
<%= @var %>
```

So, when I visit the URL localhost:3000/controller_as/index (I mean, the one that corresponds the index action of controller_a.rb) I must obtain the next in my browser:

```
example
```

I mean, I must perform controller_b other_index action and render other_index.html.erb

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor the logic of controller_b into the model. Alternative would be to use AJAX to call controller_b from the index page of controller_a